# matplotlib ticker adjust decimal points of tick that use formatter.limits

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

In case using ticker formatter.limits and use mathtext, as code below.
The result is excellent; however, I could not adjust the decimal points in (for example) the secondary axes.
It seems the matplotlib decides how much decimal to be shown, such that I could not maintain consistency between different plots.
For example, in this example, I want to force it to get only 2 or 1 decimal point in the secondary axis.

Here is the simple code

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['axes.formatter.limits'] = [-4, 6]
plt.rcParams["axes.autolimit_mode"] = "round_numbers" 
plt.rcParams["axes.formatter.use_mathtext"] = True

x = np.linspace(0, 4)
y = np.linspace(0, 2.5)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=300)
ax.plot(x, y)
secax = ax.twiny()
axlim = ax.get_xlim()
secax_xlim = [axlim[0]*22.76847e-6,
              axlim[1]*22.76847e-6]
secax.set_xlim(secax_xlim)
axticks = ax.get_xticks()
secax_xtics = axticks*22.76847e-6
secax.xaxis.set_ticks(secax_xtics)
```

I know there's a lot of question relating to this matter, I tried those solutions, but it didn't work for me.
For example, if i use `secax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))`, as in those solutions or matplotlib manual, the resulting tick is 0.00 (because the actual number is around ~1e-4 or smaller).[image: the yellow: how to adjust the decimal in this case?]
If i change the number of ticks, for example multiple the number and then perform rounding, i don't know how to re-create the nice 10^-4, manually, which seems just complicates the problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you just do `secax.xaxis.set_ticks(secax_xtics.round(6))`? `.round(5)` seems to be a little too dramatic but it still works. Here is `.round(6)`:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['axes.formatter.limits'] = [-4, 6]
plt.rcParams["axes.autolimit_mode"] = "round_numbers" 
plt.rcParams["axes.formatter.use_mathtext"] = True

x = np.linspace(0, 4)
y = np.linspace(0, 2.5)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=100)
ax.plot(x, y)
secax = ax.twiny()
axlim = ax.get_xlim()
secax_xlim = [axlim[0]*22.76847e-6,
              axlim[1]*22.76847e-6]
secax.set_xlim(secax_xlim)
axticks = ax.get_xticks()
secax_xtics = axticks*22.76847e-6
secax.xaxis.set_ticks(secax_xtics.round(6))
```

[image]

Comment: Right! It is so simple why I didn't think about it before? Always round to the 'n-2' from the limits 'n'.  I didn't know as well that numpy array has method/attribute round(), thank you for showing me, I usually use np.round(arr, number).